# Qt SetRenderHints problem

Tags: qt, antialiasing

I use Qt 4.6.3 and I have a problem.

```
ui.graphicsView->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing,false);
```

but some lines colors changes. what can I do? Please help me.

I think that I cant express myself. I hava a lot of line. When I use this code same line color changes( top of line lighter than bottom of line ) I can t solve this problem.

Comment: Could your videocard be antialiasing the picture?

Comment: can you open ? When I doesnt write this code, it is not antialising. But when I write it some line color changes.

Answer (score 3):

QPainter:: Antialiasing, false is necessary to achieve a better quality paint.

sure your problem is in when you paint the lines, whenever you use the painter must save and restore the state.

```
void Line:: paint (QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option,
QWidget * widget)
{
painter-> save (); / / save
painter-> setRenderHint (QPainter:: Antialiasing);
painter-> setPen (mypen);
painter-> drawLine (...);
painter-> restore (); / / restore
}
```

when you make changes in Painter, it could become unstable if not call the methods save() and restore (). good luck